# How do I use Bash to create a copy of a file with an extra suffix before the extension?

Tags: bash, file-io

This title is a little confusing, so let me break it down. Basically I have a full directory of files with various names and extensions:

```
MainDirectory/
    image_1.png
    foobar.jpeg
    myFile.txt
```

For an iPad app, I need to create copies of these with the suffix *@2X* appended to the end of all of these file names, before the extension - so I would end up with this:

```
MainDirectory/
    image_1.png
    image_1@2X.png
    foobar.jpeg
    foobar@2X.jpeg
    myFile.txt
    myFile@2X.txt
```

Instead of changing the file names one at a time by hand, I want to create a script to take care of it for me. I currently have the following, but it does not work as expected:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_DIR=.

#if there is an argument, use that as the files directory. Otherwise, use .
if [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
  $FILE_DIR=$1
fi

for f in $FILE_DIR/*
do
  echo "Processing $f"
  filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
  extension="${filename##*.}"
  filename="${filename%.*}"
  newFileName=$(echo -n $filename; echo -n -@2X; echo -n $extension)
  echo Creating $newFileName
  cp $f newFileName
done

exit 0
```

I also want to keep this to pure bash, and not rely on os-specific calls. What am I doing wrong? What can I change or what code will work, in order to do what I need?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh -e 
cd "${1-.}"

for f in *; do  
  cp "$f" "${f%.*}@2x.${f##*.}"
done
```

Comment: didn't know about #, ##, %, and %% - very useful, thanks!  more here http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to do that with `awk` in one line like this:

```
ls -1  | awk -F "." ' { print "cp " $0 " " $1 "@2X." $2 }' | sh
```

with `ls -1` you get just the bare list of files, then you pipe `awk` to use the dot (.) as separator. Then you build a shell command to create a copy of each file.

I suggest to run the command without the last `sh` pipe before, in order to check the `cp` commands are correct. Like this:

```
ls -1  | awk -F "." ' { print "cp " $0 " " $1 "@2X." $2 }'
```